# Including tag in header

Tags: discussion

I noticed some edits that have added **[Story Identification]:** in there header below is an example.

[Short story with carnivorous organisms mimicking objects](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78607/story-identification-short-story-with-carnivorous-organisms-mimicking-objects)

Is this the preferred way?  I always though that having the tag is enough.

Comment: I noticed this happened to a recent question of mine, which is a little disturbing given my habitual hangouts on other SEs where this is explicitly discouraged and edits tend to *remove* such tags from the titles.

Comment: Note to whoever reviews the Suggested Edit queues: please **reject** such edits

Comment: @DVK These particular edits were done by a high rep user, bypassing the review queue. I agree, though, that they are largely unnecessary

Comment: @phantom42 - very similar ones appeared repeatedly in review queue recently, as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is unneeded,  if you see this in the future,  feel free to edit the question title to remove the tags, adding any appropriate tags to the tag field.

While you're there, if anything else is amiss,  please take the time to clean that up as well.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean "edit the question title [to remove the tags], adding any appropriate tags [to the tag field]", correct?

Comment: I do try and edit when I see things wrong I just wanted to ensure I wasn't aware of some new requirement.  You confirmed my suspicion though that it was wrong.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, I can edit to clarify.